# Making python input search function case insensitive

Tags: python, search

I'm creating a python 3 search function that accepts input from the user. The user inputs a string, which is then searched in a word document.

I have tested the function with 2 docx files - one with the word "hello" in it and the other with "There".

When I input the words with the exact case as they are in the docx file the search function returns the name of the file - success! However, when I input the words without the correct case I don't get anything returned.

I've seen a few questions on here about case insensitive options but I couldn't really find one that was similar enough to my project. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import os
import docx2txt

os.chdir('c:/users/Says/desktop/projectx')

path = ('c:/users/Says/desktop/projectx')

files = []

x = str(input("search: "))

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.docx'):
        files.append(file)

for i in range(len(files)):
    text = docx2txt.process(files[i])
    if x in text:
        print (files[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.lower()` to make both strings lower case.

```
if x.lower() in text.lower():
    print( files[i] )
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is which I can suggest is just convert `x` and `test` to either `upper` or `lower` and then compare as follows, it will give you desired result.

`if x.upper() in text.upper():`

`if x.lower() in text.lower():`